# Как посмотреть во что компилируется код?

Tags: javascript

Есть ли в javascript декомпилятор или дизассемблер в байткод? Вот пример из питона.

```
In [6]: def f():
   ...:     a=1
   ...:

In [7]: dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Вы уверены что используемый вами JS-интерпретатор имеет некий промежуточный код?

Comment: а что вы хотите подавать на вход такому декомпилятору?

Comment: Чтобы на этот вопрос был однозначный ответ, неплохо бы ограничиться конкретной реализацией JS. А если выбор остановится на V8, желающие ответить [могут заняться переводом](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277423/how-can-i-see-the-machine-code-generated-by-v8).

Comment: @D-side, честно говоря, не уверен, что именно это нужно автору

Comment: @Grundy это смотря какой интерпретатор. В контексте V8 ответ на этот вопрос именно такой, но для всех реализаций ответ (а) не всегда существует, и (б) нужно смотреть отдельно каждый случай.

Comment: @Grundy я хочу посмотреть во что компилируется некий код, как в примере из питона. Собственно, об этом недвусмысленно говорит название вопроса. Подходит любой способ ведущий к результату.

Comment: @D-side меня в принципе устроит любая популярная реализация.

Answer (score 2):

Для V8 ([js-движка из хромиума/хрома](https://github.com/v8/v8)) можно использовать встроенный дизассемблер:

Сначала собрать движок их исходников, включив поддержку дизассемблера:

```
make ia32.release objectprint=on disassembler=on
```

Потом запустить d8 shell, с опциями

```
out/ia32.release/d8 --print-opt-code --code-comments --trace-hydrogen your_app.js
```

Первые две опции распечатают ассемблерный код с комментариями. Третья опция сгенерирует трейс, который можно будет просмотреть с помощью C1Visualizer.

<sub>решение честно взял с [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-view-the-machine-code-produced-by-v8-in-Chrome), на последних исходниках v8 не проверял</sub>

Соответствующие опции для spidermonkey (движка FF):

```
IONFLAGS=codegen js --ion-offthread-compile=off app.js
```

<sub>взято с [enSO: Print ion monkey generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744110/print-ion-monkey-generated-code)</sub>

Comment: Я как раз поправил вопрос - а во что дизассемблируется код? Мне нужен байткод, нативный код слишком сложен. Т.е. это не нужно http://stackoverflow.com/a/1197559/2112218

Comment: @SmitJohnth, у яваскрипта **нет** байткода

Comment: @SmitJohnth в большинстве случаев используется компиляция напрямую в машинный код минуя стадию создания байткода. Однако, вы можете найти старые версии которые использовали байткод, к примеру старый [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Internals/Bytecode) в котором есть компилятор в байткод.

Comment: @Grundy вообще нет что ли? А декомпиляторов инструкций в js тоже нет?

Comment: @AlexKrass насколько он старый? Насколько неактуален?

Comment: @SmitJohnth спецификация не требует. И в V8 реализовали без байткода.